Don't Bell tests assume entanglement to begin with?
In descriptions of Bell-type tests (or EPR-inspired tests), the explanation always starts with the assumption that a source produces a pair of entangled particles.
For instance: Aspect, Grangier and Roger (1981) open by saying, "a source emits pairs of spin-1/2 particles, in a singlet state (or pairs of photons in a similar nonfactorizing state)." (p.91) And Bell himself (1964) writes, "the EPR argument is the following. Consider a pair of spin one-half particles formed somehow in the singlet spin state and moving freely in opposite directions." (p.195) This derives from a paper by Bohm and Aharonov (1957), where they state, "We consider a molecule of total spin zero consisting of two atoms, each of spin one-half." (p.1070)
The whole point of starting with spin-1/2 particles is that they are already in a "nonfactorizing state", i.e., they are "entangled". Because they are entangled, you are assured that when you measure the spin of one, the spin of the other (along the same axis) will be anticorrelated. Starting with this assumption, the Bell test goes on to ask what happens if you measure different axes on each particle. It is assumed, not demonstrated (at least in all the descriptions I have read, including those above) that the particles are in fact 100% anticorrelated when measured along the same axis.
Without this assumption, the Bell test falls apart, because an ensemble of factorizable particles (i.e. unentangled, unrelated particles) put through the Bell test would violate Bell's Inequality without transgressing locality. But such an ensemble would not demonstrate anywhere near 100% anticorrelation along the same axis of measurement.
It seems strange to me that all the descriptions of the Bell test that I am familiar with do not start by saying "We checked and made sure that when measuring the same axis, we had near 100% anticorrelation, and only then proceeded with the actual Bell test." It is so crucial to the argument that I would have thought experimental evidence of it would be easier to find.
So my question is twofold: (1) Are there any experiments that confirm that the kind of particles used in Bell tests (spin 1/2, etc.) are in fact anticorrelated 100% of the time when measured along the same axis? (2) Why is such information not included in the Bell test descriptions themselves?
User Martin's answer to this question is relevant, specifically their answer to point "1"---but unfortunately I don't see how it actually answers the question.
REFERENCES
Aspect, Grangier, and Roger (1982) "Experimental Realization of
Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen-Bohm Gedankenexperiment: A New Violation of
Bell's Inequalities," Physical Review Letters, 49:2, pp. 91-94
Bell (1964) "On the Einstein Podolsky Rosen Paradox," Physics, 1:3,
pp.195-200
Bohm and Aharonov (1957) "Discussion of Experimental Proof for the
Paradox of Einstein, Rosen, and Podolsky," Physical Review, 108:4,
pp.1070-76

"an ensemble of factorizable particles (i.e. unentangled, unrelated particles) put through the Bell test would violate Bell's Inequality without transgressing locality. But such an ensemble would not demonstrate anywhere near 100% anticorrelation along the same axis of measurement." Could you explicitly show this ensemble, for example by providing a density matrix?

Well, all I had in mind here was any pair of particles that are not prepared in the way apparently required by the Bell test. Say, two electrons that have nothing to do with each other, so that when one is spin up the other can also be spin up without violating energy conservation. My point was simply that, if you performed the same kind of measurements as are done in the normal Bell test, but upon particles that are not specially prepared, so that they can be any combination of up/down regardless of the measured axis, Bell's inequality would be trivially violated.

@MichaelPierce in the case of non entangled particles like the example you gave, Bell's inequality will not be violated. If you believe so please give a quantitative example

Without taking anything away from the correct and concise answer of @benrg: I'd like to address a couple of specific points in the original question.
The references (Bohm, Bell, Aspect et al) are great, classic papers.  But it should be clear that there has been a lot of research in the intervening decades.  Bell tests are so common they are performed regularly in undergraduate labs.  The following paper explains this and is an excellent reference to understand how modern entanglement is created between photons using Parametric Down Conversion (PDC):
Entangled photons, nonlocality and Bell inequalities in the undergraduate laboratory

Photons from PDC can be entangled as correlated or anti-correlated.  This is done by firing a laser at a specific type of crystal, and collecting the entangled pairs as they are produced.  Only about 1 in 100 million photons (rough estimate) from the source split and come out as an entangled pair.

You could say that there is something of an assumption involved in Bell tests, but it is not much.  You say: "It is assumed, not demonstrated (at least in all the descriptions I have read, including those above) that the particles are in fact 100% anticorrelated when measured along the same axis."  Actually, all Bell tests necessarily demonstrate the appropriate "perfect" (100%) as part of the experiment, but it is usually glossed over.  You don't get sufficient/suitable experimental results if you don't start with a good source of entangled pairs.

So please take a look at the reference I gave, its Section VI is called "Tuning The State".  They discuss their efforts to get an quality entangled source, what is labeled there as |ψ EPR>.  EPR being the paper that got Bell to thinking in the first place.  They present their results for entangled correlations (actually matches rather than correlations) as measured in test runs once suitable tuning is completed. The data points are plotted against the Quantum Mechanical prediction for entangled photon pairs, which is the sinusoidal curve in Figures 3 and 4.  It is a little hard to see, but the predictions of a Hidden Variable theory (figure 4, dashed line) are different.  So if there were unentangled photon pairs being produced, the results would be closer to that than the one that is a sine wave.

Hopefully this answers your question.  Entangled systems have signature statistics and these are in fact demonstrated before starting - even if it is not always clearly explained.  And in advanced experiments, the reader is often assumed to know that occurred just by mentioning they use a PDC source; you will then find a reference in the paper to another paper where that is explained.  That way, the paper can be more concise, given their expected audience.

Here is a more modern research paper which is advanced, but is one of the most cited of all Bell tests (2413 per Google Scholar).  One of the authors (Zeilinger) shared the 2022 Nobel for this and other work, along with Aspect (for the paper you cited).


Violation of Bell's inequality under strict Einstein locality conditions
There is substantial discussion of what they did to verify they have a good entangled source (pages 3 and 4), and you will see diagrams (figure 3) similar to the other paper.
Cheers,
-DrC

The proof of Bell's inequality doesn't depend on any assumptions about quantum mechanics or quantum systems. Bell's argument has two parts:

From certain classical assumptions ("local realism"), you can prove an inequality.
There exists a set of measurements on a certain quantum system that violates the inequality.

For part 2 Bell chose idealized Stern-Gerlach measurements on a Bell pair. Those have the property that you get perfect anticorrelation if you measure both particles along the same axis, but that fact isn't needed to find a violation of the inequality. Real experiments typically use axes of 0° and 90° for one particle and 45° and 135° for the other*, meaning that the particles are never measured along the same axis. They find a violation of the CHSH inequality in those measurement results, and that's sufficient to disprove local realism.
* Actually they use photons and polarization angles that are half those I listed.

"that fact isn't needed to find a violation of the inequality." Gotcha. That answers my question (2). As for my question (1): "Bell chose idealized Stern-Gerlach measurements on a Bell pair. Those have the property that you get perfect anticorrelation if you measure both particles along the same axis." My question is, are there any experiments that clearly demonstrate that this is the case? Regardless of whether it is or isn't actually important for the Bell test itself?

@MichaelPierce full anticorrelation is not a problem for local realism, you can get perfect anticorrelation by splitting pairs of socks and sending them on opposite directions, one will be a left one and the other a right one. The correlations become impossible to be modeled classically only when you make combinations of measurements in different directions, such as, but not limited to, the ones Bell found.
